# configure WildFly to log io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener only

Tags: logging, overriding, wildfly, categories, undertow

I'm trying to log only one specific part of undertow, e.g. the very moment a call enters.
Everything works but very verbose when I add

```
        <logger category="io.undertow" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
```

It produces the following output

```
curl localhost:8080

00:31:05,684 TRACE     default I/O-12            io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent Opened connection with /127.0.0.1:61019
00:31:05,714 DEBUG     default I/O-12            io.undertow.util.PathMatcher.match Matched default handler path /
00:31:05,717 TRACE     default task-1            io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResourceManager.getFileResource Found path resource  from path resource manager with base /Users/...
00:31:05,718 TRACE     default task-1            io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResourceManager.getFileResource Found path resource index.html from path resource manager with base /Users/...
00:31:05,723 TRACE     default task-1            io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.startResponse Starting to write response for HttpServerExchange{ GET / request {Accept=[*/*], User-Agent=[curl/7.64.1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], Last-Modified=[Wed, 27 Feb 2019 17:49:04 GMT], Content-Length=[1496], Content-Type=[text/html], Accept-Ranges=[bytes], Date=[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 23:31:05 GMT]}}
00:31:05,731 INFO      default task-1            io.undertow.server.handlers.accesslog.JBossLoggingAccessLogReceiver.logMessage 127.0.0.1 [18/Mar/2021:00:31:05 +0100] 0.030 30 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 "curl/7.64.1"
```

But this gets very quickly very, very verbose.
I'm only interested in the first line

```
io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent
```

Here is my logging configuration from the standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
        <use-deployment-logging-config value="true"/>
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5.5p %3.-3X{userThreadID} %t %10.-10X{userPrincipalName} %C.%M %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5.5p %3.-3X{userThreadID} %t %10.-10X{userPrincipalName} %C.%M %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Any thoughts? It is probably not undertow specific but needs to override a config file within the library but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try enabling trace logging for `io.undertow.request.io`.

Comment: unfortunately that is also not working. have you tested it and could share your logging configuration?

Comment: I got that from the [source](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1768c88a6632d81e6fa1fd1436326cd49cbd221c/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/protocol/http/HttpOpenListener.java#L105-L107) which uses the category [`io.undertow.request.io`](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1768c88a6632d81e6fa1fd1436326cd49cbd221c/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/UndertowLogger.java#L74)